# Python regex, how to replace text between two words in a parapgraph?

Tags: python, regex

say I have a multiline string that looks like this:

```
"""
Some initial text....
Heading1
Some other text.....
Heading2
Some more text....
"""
```

So to find the text bewteen Heading1 and Heading2, I try this:

```
search1 = re.search('(Heading1)(.*)(Heading2)', string, flags=re.DOTALL)
print "Search result: \n" + str(search1.group(0))
```

Which gives me all the text between & including Heading1 and Heading2, now I'm trying to use re.sub to replace text between Heading1 and Heading2 with this:

```
new_text = re.sub('(Heading1)(.*)(Heading2)', r"\1 replaced with python script \3", string, flags=re.DOTALL)
```

But I'm getting the error:

```
TypeError: sub() got an unexpected keyword argument 'flags'
```

How do I get it so that my final output is this?:

```
"""
Some initial text....
Heading1
replaced with python script
Heading2
Some more text....
"""
```

Many thanks.

Comment: It looks like [the code is working](https://ideone.com/MfvKsF). Is it Python 2.7? (Note I would choose lazy matching for this if you have multiple paragraphs: `(Heading1)(.*?)(Heading2)`). Well, it [also works with Python 3.x](https://ideone.com/ufo8Mv).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use DOTALL modifier inside your regex also.

```
new_text = re.sub(r'(?s)(Heading1)(.*?)(Heading2)', r"\1 replaced with python script \3", string)
```

Comment: or `r'(Heading1)([\s\S]*?)(Heading2)'`

Comment: @AvinashRaj great answer! Can you recommend any good regex tutorial?

Comment: I learned all the regex stuffs from SO itself. This site http://www.regular-expressions.info/ covers alll the regex flavours.

Comment: @AvinashRaj top users from chennai number 2

Comment: Gethu ponga kalakuringha

Comment: @AvinashRaj ama eppa than one yearha vela seyuran REGEXha doubt :p